# I have problem with List View in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have list view which contains 2 buttons and 2 textviews. I change the text of button on Click event. but when I scroll the listview the text of button is changed. How to overcome this problem?

example.
[text1][text2][button hide][button2]---> this is my list view item

when I click "button hide" the text of button is change to ""button unhide"
this is similar for all items in listview

when I scroll the list view the text of button change  to "button hide"

so, how should I overcome this problem?

Comment: Please write your code so that we can help you

Comment: Generally speaking, ListViews do not work well without an up-to-date model backing them. Update your model!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably having problem with reusing views. Please provide some code so we can point it out. Generally refer to: [Toggle button in a list view loose their state when scrolled of screen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712441/toggle-button-in-a-list-view-loose-their-state-when-scrolled-of-screen-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

www.java2s.com
http://developer.openplug.com/index.php

// location services in dip
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html
java tutorial
http://www.roseindia.net/java/

Currancy convertor webservices
http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=2&WSID=10

reve. geo coding
http://www.smnirven.com/?p=39

Animation and Android webapplication
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/android/9781449399122/animation/chapanimation#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0NDkzOTkxMjIvNTQ=

http://www.123eng.com/forum/index.php?f=10

2.2. Setting the geoposition

You can set the geoposition the the Android emulator via telnet. Open a console and connect to your device. The port number of your device can be seen in the title area of your emulator.

: telnet localhost 5554
Set the position via the following command.
geo fix 13.24 52.31

//current location co-ordinates
[Customize My Location Overlay Update Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460661/customize-my-location-overlay-update-times)
http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/ 
http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/615-location-api-and-google-maps-in-android-tutorial.html
Emuletor setting use google emulator,  type cmd in camand promt of os "telnet localhost 5556(device code)" for set geo point "geo fix 18.32 73.52"

// map example
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

key tool cmd for obtaining 
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

// contact demos
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/2/

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Animation.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/10/android-full-application-tutorial.html

//proximetry alert 
http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/07/part-1-developing-

proximity-alerts-for-mobile-applications-using-the-android-platform/

http://www.vogella.de/code/codeandroid.html

// Number picker
http://www.technologichron.net/?p=42

font add
http://javafriend.yolasite.com/myandroid/page/2

sms apps
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39495/1954

application icon
http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

link for click event of list items
[Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709166/android-listview-elements-with-multiple-clickable-buttons)

[How to create multiple buttons at runtime? + android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763366/how-to-create-multiple-buttons-at-runtime-android)

http://wiki.millennialmedia.com/index.php/Android

// contact
http://wubbahed.com/2007/12/21/android-development-contacts/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013131/add-organization-details-in-contact-list